# How to open image on the right content page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to open an image from the sidebar to the right panel. it needs to stay in the same page.

For example something like this. https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_sidebar

Let's say Link 1 and Link 2 and Link 3 are images, by clicking on one of them i want to have the image be displayed on the right side where you see "my page".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>W3.CSS</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <body>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="w3-sidebar w3-light-grey w3-bar-block" style="width:25%">
      <h3 class="w3-bar-item">Menu</h3>
      <a href="img_car.jpg" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 3</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div style="margin-left:25%">

      <div class="w3-container w3-teal">
        <h1>My Page</h1>
      </div>

      <img src="img_car.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">

      <div class="w3-container">
        <h2>Sidebar Navigation Example</h2>
        <p>The sidebar with is set with "style="width:25%".</p>
        <p>The left margin of the page content is set to the same value.</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: be more specific with your question!

Comment: If you run the code you will see menu and then under menu link 1 Link 2 Link 3 etc , if for example link 1 is een img i want that img to be presented to right page content in My Page

Comment: I would advice to use can of slider as: https://css-tricks.com/css-only-carousel/

Comment: @MaxiGui Good one! is there also a way to enlarge the pictures?

Comment: sure you can just set the width you wish. I guess, you are learning, so I will let you search :)